# Is there a good reason to write code in Program.cs/main as opposed to using classes?

Tags: c#, program-entry-point

I am working on a pretty large application and my tech lead and I are not seeing eye to eye on certain things.

One of them is regarding console applications. These applications are being ported to C# from shell scripts. Some of these scripts are reasonably large (300-400 lines of code after conversion) and do things like I/O, Email and database access.

For each of these scripts I created a class. Each class has a Run method which calls any methods/operations that are within. Inside Program.cs/ main, I create an object of said class and call Run. Program.cs contains 4-5 lines of code. Clean and simple.

My tech lead wants to get rid of the script classes and just have everything inside the main method of program.cs. His reasoning is that it is too confusing the way it is.

It feels awkward having to do it this way as the class no longer becomes reusable/package-able into a class library without having to fiddle with the main method.

Unit tests seem like they are unaffected since you can instantiate Program.cs itself, but again....this feels clunky. Are there any benefits to doing it his way that I am not seeing? Are there any benefits my way? Is there a general practice when dealing with large applications and content in your main method?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: He is ​​​wrong.

Comment: You are thinking right. The only reason one would have everything in Main/ Program.cs is if it is one time piece of code quick n working. Like scripts.

Comment: This question is a better fit for programmers, IMO, hence vote to close. It really all depends on what your class does, but, in general, the Single Responsibility Principle is a good rule of thumb - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: I'm not sure "Each class has a Run method which calls any methods/operations that are within" is enough of an improvement though since that makes it seem like someone can read main without understanding what the program actually does.

Comment: I asked a colleague about this question. Their response? Everyone is wrong and it should be called via Spring.Net removing the need for any code at all in Main. This, I guess, reinforces the fact that this question isn't the greatest fit for SO.

Comment: I want some of that stuff your tech lead is onto

Comment: I think its worth looking at intelligent all-encompassing programs like `busybox` when doing something like this.  Have a look at its structure, and the handling of all those functions in one big program made from lots of sources.  I think you'll find it very enlightening.

Comment: This question is not off-topic and probably should not have been closed. Questions of the sort "*Under what circumstances do you do _____ in your code*" are well within SO's guidelines for appropriate questions. Even if the correct answer is "*never*".

Comment: @tylerl - much better fit for programmers.stackexchange.com, and just because there is a consensus among programmers here doesn't mean this question isn't opinion/discussion driven.  I voted "off topic" because I think it should be on programmers, would have voted "not constructive" if we didn't have that option.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> It feels awkward having to do it this way as the class no longer becomes reusable/package-able into a class library without having to fiddle with the main method.

It doesn't *have* to be that way.

For example, each of your scripts could still have the same structure it does, but *also* have a `private static void Main(string[] args)` method. (It could be non-private if you want - it all depends on your needs.)

That way it's standalone (can be compiled as a single input to a single output then run) which can occasionally be handy, but could *also* be used as part of a class library. The presence of a `Main` method in no way *prevents* the class being used from other classes, after all.

It's not clear whether you've got *one* `Program.cs` file or one per script. If you've got one per script, each of which is just 4-5 lines, that does seem *somewhat* pointless.

Now this certainly wouldn't be how I'd normally structure a large application - but if the point is to have several "scripts" each of which *can* be run standalone, then giving each class a `Main` method doesn't seem too bad.

In fact, what I often do for *demo* purposes is have several classes with `Main` methods in a single project, then have a separate entry point (which *is* in `Program.cs`) which uses reflection to find all the others and then allows the user/presenter to choose which one to run.

If all your code makes sense to have in a single class, then having a tiny extra entry method doesn't seem such a problem. If it's *actually* a case of too much code for a single class *regardless* of where the entry point is, that's a different matter. (So if you stuck to having a single `ScriptClass` when actually you should give different tasks to different classes, that would be bad too.) Likewise if he really is insisting on all the code being in a single *method*, that's definitely a problem for testing and maintainability.

I suggest you set the entry point disagreement aside for the moment: work out the cleanest way to structure everything *else* about the code, and then it really doesn't matter whether the `Main` method goes in `Program.cs` or within another class.

Comment: I have one Program.cs file per script as each script is a console application. The way I have it, all I do in program.cs is call ScriptClass.Run() inside of main...along with a bit of error handling. This is why it only has 4-5 lines of code. Doing it the other way, each program.cs would have 300+ lines of code (as it would be taking the content of ScriptClass and putting it into program.cs). Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @JohnnySaxx: See my edited answer - I really don't think the location of the entry point is worth worrying about. If your `ScriptClass.Run` method is still a giant 300 line method, then moving the `Main` method into a separate file hasn't done you any good. Likewise if you've been able to refactor `ScriptClass` to be broken up into testable bits, then *leaving* the `Main` method in there isn't going to do you any harm. It sounds like each script *project* is going to have the same amount of code whatever you do (the 300+ lines) - you haven't mentioned anything reusable yet, as far as I've seen

Comment: ScriptClass contains other methods. So inside of Run I have:
Run { method1(), method2()...methodn()}; 

method1-n are visible only to the unit test project where I test each one. Run is the only method exposed publicly outside of the class.

Also, thanks for the tip regarding main. Essentially ScriptClass replaces Program.cs as the entry class at which point there is no need for the later. In that case, is there really any reason why one is better than the other? Aren't you sort of doing the same thing?

Comment: @JohnnySaxx: Right - and do these methods all logically belong in the same class? If so, that's fine. The benefit to only having a single file is just that - you don't have an extra file hanging around giving no actual benefit. It's not a particularly big deal, but equally it's not a big deal to have `Main` within the same type.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're creating work for yourself, honestly. I can't tell from the details in your description - but if shell scripts have been working, why structure it where structure was apparently not needed?

You're stating that modularity and repackaging into an external library is something that you'll need to do - I would counter "why?" (this is what I mean by extra work).

If you create a simple set of methods in a single file - that's a single file! It, by definition, will be easier to work with then multiple projects etc.

That said - it's hard to know what we're talking about unless there are some more details. If it's "send a nightly report and email these people" - yeah that's something that doesn't need a class library and a ton of modularity. Run a method, you're done.

Comment: Thats the reason for my question I guess :). All the scripts have already been completed, unit tests written and all. It is having to go back and do it this way which is confusing for me as I can not see a clear reason/benefit as to why. Starting from scratch his way would definitely have been easier for me...believe me. But now, is there really a point?

Answer (score 4):

You do know that the entry point of a console application is configurable, right?

My preferred method would be:

```
class MeaningfullyNamedProgram { 
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var program = new MeaningfullyNamedProgram(args);
        program.Run();
    }

    public MeaningfullyNamedProgram(string[] args) { 
    }

    public Run() {
        // well structured, broken-out code follows 
    }
}
```

Point the entry point of the project at MeaningfullyNamedProgram.Main

*NOTE: I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader, but you could create a base class for this using generics, and save yourself some typing.*

Answer (score 3):

Your tech lead needs a good talking to! Putting everything into the Program.cs is not the way forward.

Answer (score 3):

Well, his way is conceptually simpler, in that it's how programs were written before the subroutine was invented ....

Your way is better: it supports reusability and would be easier to modify and to debug.

The only other justification I can think of for his way was that if it was taking significantly longer for you to do it your way than it would be to do it his way.  But that's a case of short-term thinking on his part.  Your way will stand the test of time better.

Answer (score 2):

Your tech lead is wrong. The method you propose is a lot more reasonable -- it allows for the consolidation of different scripts easily. Each script having its own `Main` method can get clunky, especially if you are planning on having an application that can run several of these at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the logic out into a separate class (or classes) is the way to go.  Putting it all into one spot violates the principles of SOLID and DRY design.  You're definitely on the right track with your approach.

The more you keep your classes focused on single roles the easier your life will be for maintenance and testing.

Answer (score 1):

If the functionality can be consumed by other means than a console program, of course you should keep them in a nicelly modelled class library. To save a few lines of code by entangeling command line parameter processing with encapsulated functionality does not make sense given the fact that the concerns were originally separated anyway. Maybe your tech lead should find more productive tasks for you IMHO.