# .net Console App that summons a form

Tags: c#, .net

Im coding a console app that summons a form,

I found this and it work:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

[STAThread]
static void Main() 
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.Run(new MyForm()); 
}
```

Update:

Found the answer to my question my code is now working thank you for your answers.

Comment: tried adding a function into it ?what result you got ?

Comment: Where will I put the function? Sorry, I really code in vb im trying to work things out with c#.

Comment: what function you need to add ?

Comment: A button, label, textbox and a function that edits the label text depending on the contents of the textbox.

Comment: Inside your class MyForm

Comment: Really a -1? this question is as unique as it is.

Comment: actually you want to make a console appliation or windows ?

Comment: As I said a console application that summons form.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add buttons or any other controls in `program.cs` in Forms application whether it is VB or C# as it is not indented for designing.

```
static void Main()
```

Signifies the starting point of the program.You can design and add functions by adding new forms to the project.

For more on developing the project you can refer the links below,it would be helpful :

**Difference between Form1.cs, Program.cs**
[Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/daf4be8a-5fb7-4c54-8152-b9afd340f4c4/newbie-difference-between-form1cs-programcs-?forum=Vsexpressvcs)

**Main method in c#**[Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/479467/Main-Method-in-Csharp)

**Create a C# Windows Forms Application**[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/360kwx3z(v=vs.90).aspx)

**Reasons to write code in program.cs**[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904724/is-there-a-good-reason-to-write-code-in-program-cs-main-as-opposed-to-using-clas)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I'm NOT making actual forms with it, what I am doing is basically a proof of concept of how to summon a form with a console and insert a method into it.

Comment: but as you have said : A button, label, textbox and a function that edits the label text depending on the contents of the textbox..we cannot design them in program.cs

Comment: Actually you can insert label and textbox into it, I can.
What Im unable to do is insert a method into it.